# How can i make a Glass material that doesn't need any light to shine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I'm trying to make a PNG Rain animation with Alpha Channel and then i need to import that into another software, the thing is that i created a glass material in order to give the water-drops a kind of transparent texture, and it works on the preview of the material, the thing is that it needs light (any lamp) to work, but on this case i do not want to add any light since i need it almost as a plain illumination, is it possible to make the material work without light? like an Emission material but with this glass material?

[image]

Image Reference (without the background)

[image]

Comment: Could you find a reference image that look like what you want? I'm not sure I understand the difference between lamp light reflected from a material, vs light emitted from the material itself.

Comment: Something like this (without the background)
http://wallhud.com/download?filename=2014/12/rain_water_drop_wallpapers.jpg

Comment: maybe an environement texture mapped as reflection with transparency on the drop objects for a fake refraction/reflection effect

Comment: How can i hide the enviroment so it doesnt appear on the Render?

Comment: @beavoru uncheck environment from the render layers

Comment: @beavoru or check  film "transparent" option in render settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background material to white or light grey in enviroment.
Turn on ambient inclusion in enviroment settings.
Set film to transparent in render settings.

That said, without a directional light you won't get shadows or reflection that make it look like rain.  So you might want to add a light, use an image or movie in the background that the rain could reflect, or set up a light that only throws shadows and place it directly above your rain.

Andrew price did a great tutorial that included rain on the camera, if you have any other issues you might want to check it out on blenderguru.com